# Регулярка для текста в кавычках

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, shell

Пусть есть строка

```
"Ka": ["T<sub>A</sub>","desc"]
```

Нужна регулярка, которая возвращает текст в кавычках.

я пытался `sed -r 's/\("[^"]*"\)/\1/' file`, но не удается. По идее нужно чтобы при обращении \1 выводилось значение в 1 кавычках, \2 - во вторых кавычках , \3 - в третьих кавычках. Возможно ли это через sed?

Comment: для sed надо каждую группу выводимую отдельно описывать. \2 соответствует вторым круглым скобкам в строке. т.е. только `("[^"]").*("[^"]")` и т.п.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо Вам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант выглядит так.

```
sed -r 's/("[^"]*")[^"]*("[^"]*")[^"]*("[^"]*").*/\3/' 1.txt
```

Comment: Я только не понимаю, а что это за штучки *Выполнить код* *Копировать ...* , что они делают в вопросе и ответе и вообще для чего они здесь?

Comment: @Sebefour, а не надо `.*` на 'некавычку' заменить между группами?

Answer (score 0):

Так же вы можете использовать AWK. задаем разделитель полей кавычку и каждое второе сопоставление - это наше слово в кавычках. Для вывода содержимого 3х кавычек используем:

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}'
```

Answer (score 0):

как я понял, надо извлечь третью группу символов, заключённую в кавычки (в примере — `"desc"`). это можно сделать, например, так:

```
$ sed -r 's/("[^"]*){4}("[^"]*").*/\2/' file
```

объяснение: в первую группу (заключённую в круглые скобки) попадает (последовательно) четыре повторения группы, состоящей из кавычки (<kbd>"</kbd>) и «любого количества не-кавычек» (<kbd>[^"]*</kbd>). повторения задаются квантификатором <kbd>{число}</kbd>.

а во вторую группу попадает: кавычка, «любое количество не-кавычек» и ещё одна кавычка.

оставшиеся символы «поглощаются» квантификатором <kbd>.*</kbd>.